# npm init vue@latest command prompts but does not advance

Tags: vue.js, npm, installation, cmd, vuejs3

I tried to install `vue.js` with `npm init vue@latest`. It prompts me for the project name, but does not advance beyond that.

If I press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, the console shows this:

```bash
Operation cancelled
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\andres.marin
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c create-vue
```

I ran `cmd.exe` with administrator permissions.

`node` version 16.19.0, `npm` version is 8.19.3.

[image: console image]

Thanks for your help.

I also tried change `node` version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the same commands by using [powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/overview?view=powershell-7.3) ? you might get different results. Good luck!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).